# Get device UDID (40 digit id) programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image]In my app, I am trying to get all information of the device and to be displayed in app screen.

I got some of the informations, but not getting code to obtain UDID, Serial number and model identifier of a device, what we can able to see in iTunes.

I can able to get UUID, but my request is to get UDID of the device. I got some apps in which they are getting device info like this.

I will be very helpful if I get any solution in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They posted for UUID. I need to get UDID, serial number etc.

Comment: have you find any solution then please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as of iOS 6.

[Link #1](https://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html)

Money quote:

> As reported by 9to5Mac (and confirmed by Macworld), Apple alerted
>   developers of a cut-off date for new apps or app updates that access
>   an iOS device’s UDID (Universal Device ID), an area of security and
>   privacy concern.

[Link #2](https://www.macworld.com/article/2010961/rights-group-lauds-privacy-changes-in-apples-ios-6.html)

Extended money quote:

> With iOS 6 Apple has also completely eliminated its controversial
>   Universal Device IDs (UDID) and replaced it with a more
>   privacy-friendly way for application vendors and advertisers to
>   identify specific devices, Hall said,
>
> Apple’s UDIDs are basically a set of alphanumeric characters that are
>   used to uniquely identify an iPhone or iPad. The numbers are designed
>   to let application developers track how many users have downloaded
>   their application and to gather other information for data analytics.

From the same article, the way to go now is:

> With the new iOS 6 the company has gone one step further by
>   eliminating UDIDs completely and replace with a set of three new devie
>   identifiers. One is a vendor specific identifier that can be used by
>   application vendors to recognize specific devices, another is designed
>   for use by online advertisers and the third is an application-specific
>   ID. Unlike UDID’s, the new identifiers are not persistent and can be
>   cleared, though the device has to be completely reset to get rid of
>   the advertiser identities, Hall said.

In conclusion, the correct way *is* to either (a) use UUID or (b) *ask* your user for the device's UDID.

Comment: Awesome answer!. Thanks. But I wonder how the apps in store getting the device UDID? Say for example UDID finder, Device Inspectors are the apps available in the store. They are getting device UDID.

Comment: @JosechristyMartin Take a look at UDID Finder's last update, which was in 2010. As dfd stated, this functionality is not available with new apps or app updates.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I did an online search and found a few websites out there too. One, easy-idid.com (sorry I will not provide the link), requires you to tether your device to the computer - an immediate flag for me. I checked the page source and found things like *"...is simple and based on Apple's enterprise deployement policies for iDevices...stated
in the provisioning profile we use, and which contains Device enrollment challenge...Additionnally, to be installed, the profile needs user's acknowledgement."* Not only is this sketchy, it still requires the user's permission.

Answer (score -4):

**You can use this (Swift 3):**

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Comment: Not UUID, what I need is UDID.